# ArrayList for Audio player cannot convert to Int

Tags: java

So I followed a tutorial for an AudioPlayer for part an App I am making, however I am coming across this error:

Error:(30, 43) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Here are the code sections:

```
playAudio(audioList.get(0).getData());
```

This calls the following Method:

```
private void playAudio(int audioIndex) {
    //Check is service is active
    if (!serviceBound) {
        //Store Serializable audioList to SharedPreferences
        StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
        storage.storeAudio(audioList);
        storage.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

        Intent playerIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
        startService(playerIntent);
        bindService(playerIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } else {
        //Store the new audioIndex to SharedPreferences
        StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
        storage.storeAudioIndex(audioIndex);

        //Service is active
        //Send a broadcast to the service -> PLAY_NEW_AUDIO
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(Broadcast_PLAY_NEW_AUDIO);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}
```

If I change it from int audioIndex to String audioIndex, it causes errors in other parts of the code where the storage is held.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm guessing `getData()` returns a `String`. You are trying to pass a `String` to a method that expects an `int` argument.

Comment: What data type does audioList.get(0).getData() return actually ?

Comment: You can use `playAudio(Integer.valueOf(audioList.get(0).getData));` . But you need to be sure that getData returns a Number which is a String . Else a NumberFormatException will occur

Answer (score 0):

The fact that a string is not a number, even when it only contains digits.

Simply use a conversion method such as Integer.valueOf() to convert the string before passing.

Where the *real* answer is: spend quite some time on studying the basics of Java. Don't get me wrong, but when you don't know about such super simple things, you are far away from doing android development.